# Issue with LocationManager's updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cmmotionmanager

I wrote an app to collect data via MotionManager, the scenario is an iPhone located inside a vehicle. I need to collection some location-related data as well (latitude, longitude and speed).
I use a Timer to collect every 150ms the MotionManager data and at the same time I store the last location update. While the motion data is collected and the values make sense, I noticed that location data is updated only every second or so, despite the settings I used for LocationManager. Below my code:

```
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
 
    motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1 / 30

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.15, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            locationLock.lock()
                if let location = locations.last {
                    lastLocation = location
                }
            locationLock.unlock()
    }
    
    
    @objc func update() {
    // function collecting the MotionManager data
    locationLock.lock()        
    // do something with lastLocation.coordinate.latitude
    // do something with lastLocation.coordinate.longitude
    locationLock.unlock()
    }
```

As the vehicle drives at least as fast as 50kmh/35mph, I would expect a new location value every 100-150ms. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Location updates only arrive about once per second regardless of speed.